# Como hacer que las columnas sean dinámicas en la librería exceljs? Problemas con el estilo

Tags: javascript, typescript, excel

Actualmente tengo dos tablas en un excel las cuales una coge el estilo(sumatorio) y la otra no(desviación) además, necesitaría que tengan un separado dinámico y este es estático, cuando las tablas tengan muchas formulas necesito que no se solapen.

```
// tabla de las desviaciones medias para cada mancha y formula
    worksheet_Resultado.getCell('B25').value = "Detergencia en Manchas por Naturaleza(desviación)";
    worksheet_Resultado.addTable({
      name: 'Composición de Análisis',
      displayName: 'Detergencia en Manchas por Naturaleza (desviación)',
      ref: 'B26',
      headerRow: true,
      totalsRow: false,
      style: {
        theme: 'TableStyleLight1',
        showRowStripes: true,
      },
      columns: columns,
      rows: resultado ,
    });
    let resultado2: Array<any> = [];
    this.getValues(tablaResultados).forEach((r: ManchaEstadistica, index: number) => {
      resultado2.push(r.formatoExcelSumatorio(array_formulas));
    });
    resultado2= resultado2.sort((a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]));
    // tabla de los sumatorios para cada mancha y formula
    worksheet_Resultado.getCell('P25').value = "Detergencia en Manchas por Naturaleza (sumatorio)";
    worksheet_Resultado.addTable({
      name: 'Composición de Análisis',
      displayName: 'Detergencia en Manchas por Naturaleza (sumatorio)',
      ref: 'P26',
      headerRow: true,
      totalsRow: false,
      style: {
        theme: 'TableStyleLight1',
        showRowStripes: true,
      },
      columns: columns,
      rows: resultado2 ,
    });
    
    // descarga el fichero
    workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then(function (data) {
      var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8"});
      FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'ensayo.xlsx');
    });
```